# Function "setFormula()" does not result in working sheets formula

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to add this formula to a Google sheet via Google apps script:

=WENN(UND(B997>2.3,C997>380),1,0)

The row obviously need to be a variable. When I enter the formula manually. It shows expected results.

Now I would like to add this formula to each new row in the sheet together with other values.

The basic code looks as follows:

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
 var rows =ss.getLastRow()+1;
 var formula = "=WENN(UND(B" + rows + ">2.3,C" + rows + ">380),1,0)";
  
  ss.getRange(rows, 1).setValue("Datum");
  ss.getRange(rows, 2).setValue(2.5);
  ss.getRange(rows, 3).setValue(300);
  ss.getRange(rows, 4).setFormula(formula);
```

In principle the code works and column 4 shows exactly the desired formula including correct row.

However the Google sheet always shows, that the function "WENN" (=if in German) is unknown.

[image]

Strangely, when I copy the inserted formula and paste it manually to another row, it works perfectly.

Has anybody made similar experiences and found the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Meantime I found the problem myself: The above approach is correct, however it only works when using the english formulas.

Hence the line

```
 var formula = "=WENN(UND(B" + rows + ">2.3,C" + rows + ">380),1,0)";
```

works as intended wenn changing formula the following way:

```
 var formula = "=IF(AND(B" + rows + ">2.3,C" + rows + ">380),1,0)";
```

Hope this helps somebody.